# Reference hyperlink from button with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, dom-events

I have a web page with dynamically generated hyperlinks in a grid view. For every hyperlink should be a corresponding button, which does nothing else than calling the link. How can I reference the href property from my clientclick button event and call it?

Comment: Why bother? I would just style your links, using CSS `text-decoration:none;` and making sure the `:hover` and `:visited` pseudo-class does what you want. This would also be the progressive enhancement solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you are retrieving the hyperlink, you could just do something like the following:

Html:

```
<a id="dyn_link_00" href="https://duckduckgo.com/" target="_blank">Duck, duck, GO!!!!</a>
```

Javascript:

```
// we assume that the current index is 00 and link is defined in scope.
link = document.getElementById('dyn_link_' + currentIndex);
console.log(link.href.toString()); // yields https://duckduckgo.com/ 
                                   // (toString() might not be necessary)
```